# speed up the AVR ISR

Tags: c, avr, pwm, isr, attiny

I am wondering if it is possible to speed up the ISR without changing the prescaler.
I have a timer with 2 compare registers A and B.

COMPA is used for a PWM output from around 22% up to 100%. This has a fixed frequency and I am not allowed to change it at least not much.

Now I would like to use the COMPB with around 4 times the speed but with a fixed duty cycle of 50%.

If I set the OCIE0B bit in TIMSK0 for the attiny13 can I do the following to speed things up?
Or am I misunderstanding something here?

```
ISR(TIM0_COMPB_vect){
    switch (timing){
        case 0:
            OCR0B = 63;
            PORTB ^= (1 << PB3);
            timing = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            OCR0B = 127;
            PORTB ^= (1 << PB3);
            timing = 2;
            break;
        case 2:
            OCR0B = 191;
            PORTB ^= (1 << PB3);
            timing = 3;
            break;
        case 3:
            OCR0B = 255;
            PORTB ^= (1 << PB3);
            timing = 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanx :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very efficiently by creatively using the Normal Mode.

The trick is to set the prescaller to get a clock period that is *double* what you want the variable-duty PWM signal to run at. So if, for example, you want that to PWM at 1Mhz, set the prescaller to 2Mhz.

Assume the variable duty cycle PWM is on pin A and the fixed 50% 4x clock signal is on pin B. (You can also swap these and and also update the code everything will still work)

1. Enable interrupts for "On compare match B" and "Overflow".
2. Force pin `A` high with a force compare match.  (Alternately you can skip this step and instead use the inverse of the desired duty cycle in step 7)
3. Set the `COM` bits for 'A' to `Toggle on match`.
4. Leave the `COM` bits for `B` to off. Assumes you have DDR set for this pin to be normal GPIO.
5. Set the `OCR` for `B` to `128`.
6. Set the WGM timer mode to `0` - "Normal Mode".
7. Set the OCR for `A` whatever you want the variable duty cycle to be. Note that you might need to special case here for extreme values of `0` and/or `255` depending on what you want to have happen  (just turn the pin `ON` of `OFF` with GPIO).

You can repeat step 6 anytime you want to change the duty cycle of `A` and it will update on the next `TOP`.

Once you do these steps, the `A` pin will output the desired duty cycle at 1/2 the prescaller clock and the `B` will output 50% duty at 2x the prescaller clock (which is the desired 4x of the `A` period).

Here is the ISR code (note that I am not sure what the TOV vector is called in the attiny13 headers [it is sometimes different across AVRs] so you might have to edit the `TIM0_OVF_vect` name)...

```
ISR(TIM0_COMPB_vect,TIM0_OVF_vect){
    PINB |= (1 << PB3);   // Compiles to a single cycle SBI
}
```

See how this works?

Note that setting a bit in the `PIN` register actually toggles the `PORT` bit. This is a quirk of the AVR GPIOs that is documented in the datasheets.

Hopefully  this is fast enough. If you really want to squeeze every last cycle out, you can even potentially save the 2 cycles of the RJMP from the interrupt vector by putting the single `SBI` instruction that the ISR compiles down to directly into the interrupt vector table with a trailing `RETI`, but this is more complicated!

Comment: Right, this is better. But I still need to set it back to 0 otherwise overflow...
And I can not use normal mode, because I am using this timer for hardware PWM.

Comment: "But I still need to set it back to 0 otherwise overflow" ->

If the `OCR` is 192 and you increment it by 64, it will overflow to 0. This is defined (and desired!) behavior.

Comment: "And I can not use normal mode, because I am using this timer for hardware PWM" -> Normal mode supports hardware PWM. I've updated the steps for exactly how to set every register to get the desired result (and also reduced the ISR down to a single cycle!)

Answer (score 0):

Focusing solely on the C code aspects, then this can be trivially optimized as:

```
ISR(TIM0_COMPB_vect)
{
  static const uint8_t OCR[4] = {63,127,191,255};
  OCR0B = OCR[timing];

  PORTB ^= 1u << PB3;

  timing++;
  if(timing==4)
    timing=0;
}
```

Disassembled on gcc AVR -O3 (with all variables/registers volatile) this brings down the amount of instructions from ~50 to  ~20, so it's about twice as fast and takes less memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the fastest equivalent version of the supplied code, then here it is...

```
ISR(TIM0_COMPB_vect){
    OCR0B += 64;
    PINB |= (1 << PB3);
}
```

- `OCR0B` will overflow every 4 passes, which is defined behavior. Probably wise to initialize `OCR0B` to some non-zero number like `1` to avoid edge cases.
- This avoids all variables and memory access - only register access.
- Avoids all compares and braches.
- The `PINB` method of toggling the pin compiles down to a single `SBI` instruction rather than a PUSH, load, XOR, store, POP sequence.

...but again, none of this matters if it does not work and unless you are using one of the two "immediate OCR update" modes, then updating OCR in the middle of a timer cycle will have no effect.